# How to enable mixed platform on Docker on year 2022?

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

I checked out some tutorials but the Daemon tab is already missing with the current version of Docker Desktop(4.8.1). Under the "Docker Engine" tab, I set the 'experimental' field to 'true' but it looks like it is still not working.

The "platform" parameter isn't working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What works:

- Running linux based containers, `Switch to Windows containers...` and
  run windows containers. Running containers will keep on running. You'll find it on right-click on system tray
  of Docker Desktop.
- Pull windows and linux based containers in Windows mode, but NOT in linux mode
- Creating a compose file and use the keys `platform: linux` and `platform: windows` mixed, while running Windows container mode. Compose will choose the daemon for you.

You can not:

- Build images on a daemon not supporting the OS of the image, see [Roadmap](https://github.com/docker/roadmap/issues/79)

I don't know whats wrong in your case. In Windows Mode with

```
{
  "experimental": true
}
```

(you have to set it again in Windows Mode, there are 2 different daemon settings)
you should be able to pull linux and windows images. Just checked with docker desktop 4.9.0 (prebuild), can't pull in 4.8.1 due to bug in proxy settings..

Comment: If I'm using Linux container and do the "docker pull --platform=linux ubuntu", it works fine but not "docker pull --platform=windows mcr.microsoft.com/windows:20H2" which returns an error "image operating system "windows" cannot be used on this platform".

But if I switch to Windows container, I can pull Windows images using the command above. But now, pulling an Ubuntu image is failing returning an error "Error response from daemon: unsupported os linux".

Comment: I see, so I should just wait for the next stable version to fix the bug? Thanks!

Comment: Should work with 4.8.1 as well. I just can't check it because another bug (not respecting proxy settings) prevents me from pulling images on this version. You tried the stuff from my answer? Switch to Windows Mode, set `experimental` flag again for windows daemon and pull both?

Comment: It worked! But it I'm already on version 4.8.2.